# Unusual base url in Codeigniter with Chrome

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-chrome, firefox

I found it is unusual with the latest stable version of **CI (3.03)**,

I tried echo **`base_url()`** and it returns some unusual thing,

**Note: ** I have loaded the URL helper .

The following code

```
$this->load->helper('url');
echo base_url();
```

returns `http://127.0.0.1/` (I have used `http://localhost/` to interpret the application) in Firefox.

And:

`http://::1/` (Same I have used `http://localhost/` ) in Chrome ?

Help me guys in fixing this.

Comment: Have you set url in here. `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';`

Answer (score 0):

Please remove base_url form the config file if you set there,

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Harsh Sanghani, but I wonder what goes wrong in CI's auto guess of URL ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set a base url

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';
```

Some times for me that is issue.

In older versions of CI you use to be able to leave that blank but.

**Now it is recommended that you do not leave that base_url blank.**

And I would auto load the url helper as it is the most common one.

Comment: Thanks for the info , But always I use to leave it blank until the development gets over, and CI's auto guess of URL works fine, This is the firs time  I'am experiencing the problem

Comment: It is wrong to leave it blank `WARNING: You MUST set this value!`. [Check the comment above](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php).

Answer (score 0):

In your config, use define. like below:

```
define('base_url', 'http://localhost/your_project name/');
```

And then try 
`echo base_url()` ;